# XLSM file corrupted... beyond repair?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Microsoft Excel File that I use for my budget and financial tracking.  It has some simple macros that copy the generic budget, allocates funds to different places, and processes transactions.

My wife was updating this file for the coming month, when she says she accidentally hit a few random keystrokes when our toddler grabbed her arm.

The keystrokes resulted in closing the file, but now the file will not open at all!  Opening the file prompts the user to enable editing and permit macros, but following your response, no matter what the response, the file is not opened.  Excel remains open, but no workbook !!

Any thoughts on this?  I can share the workbook and the most recently non-corrupted version (last months), but I have no idea how to correct this, if it is even possible.  Any help anyone can provide would be most appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the following?: 1) going to the view tab and `Arrange All` 2) going to the view tab and `Unhide` 3) `open and repair`

Comment: Unhide!!  That did it!  Repost as an answer and I'll flag it.  Thanks a million cybernetic.nomad!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

1) going to the view tab and `Arrange All`

2) going to the view tab and `Unhide`

3) open and repair

You're welcome